# Get request-header in web api

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, request, actionfilterattribute

I'm trying to set a header with a simple key/value-pair and want to read this from my API.
So this is my call from client:

```
public async Task<T> Auth_GetAsync<T>(string path)
{
    var client = BaseHttpClient;
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage
    {
        RequestUri = new Uri(Path.Combine(client.BaseAddress.AbsoluteUri, path)),
        Method = HttpMethod.Get,
        Headers = { {"key", "param"} }
    };
    request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(RequestHeader));
    var task = await client.SendAsync(request);
    return task.IsSuccessStatusCode
                    ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(await task.Content.ReadAsStringAsync())
                    : default(T);
}
```

when I'm trying to read the header in my action, I get it completely (with my key/value-pair)

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetAsync()
{
    var i = Request.Headers;
    return await Task.Run(() => new[] { "value1", "value2" });
}
```

when I'm trying to do this with the ActionFilterAttribute and/or the IAuthorizationFilter my header always contains other keys, but never contains my key/value-pair.
This is my Attribute:

```
public class RequiresKeyAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var req = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
        var auth = req.Headers["key"]; // this is null here
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var i = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers;
    }
}
```

My target is, that the actionfilter checks whether the key is set in the header or not. I don't always want to check in my action if the key is set and validate it,...

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there solution to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you inherited the wrong `ActionFilterAttribute` which comes from MVC, not Web Api because WebApi uses `HttpActionContext`, not `ActionExecutingContext` like below:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    //code
}
```

You just use using `System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute` from WebApi, it will be fine.

Comment: nope, since I'm using the API with MVC 5. I'm using the FilterConfig which comes from `System.Web.Mvc`. Exception is: `The given filter instance must implement one or more of the following filter interfaces: System.Web.Mvc.IAuthorizationFilter, System.Web.Mvc.IActionFilter, System.Web.Mvc.IResultFilter, System.Web.Mvc.IExceptionFilter, System.Web.Mvc.Filters.IAuthenticationFilter.`

Comment: Everything should be from `System.Web.Http`, not `System.Web.Mvc`

Comment: I see... now it's working. But then, the template provided by Visual Studio for creating a WebApi is wrong... MVC-namespace was default

Comment: Thanks. it is also answer to this question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71780279/log-httpcontext-response-headers-on-onactionexecuted-in-net-6