# Log HttpContext.Response.Headers on OnActionExecuted in .NET 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm trying to create an attribute [LogRequest] which will log HTTP request and response with  headers.

Action controller

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetCourse")]
[LogRequest]
public Course GetCourse()
{
    return new Course();
}
```

Implementation of LogRequest attribute

```
public class LogRequest : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public LogRequest() : base(typeof(LogRequestImplementation)) { }

    private class LogRequestImplementation : IActionFilter
    {
        //Log request
        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            //Here i'm logging request. This part works perfectly
        }

        //Log response
        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            IHeaderDictionary responseHeaders = context.HttpContext.Response.Headers;
            //responseHeaders is always empty.
        }
    }
}
```

**context.HttpContext.Response.Headers** is always empty. I guess i'm missing something in middleware.

Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    context.Request.EnableBuffering();
    await next();
});

app.Run();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to inherit from 'ActionFilterAttribute'

```
public class LogRequestImplementation : ActionFilterAttribute
```

To log an request data you can use 'IActionFilter' which will implement two methods.

- OnActionExecuting
- OnActionExecuted

And if you want to log response data you can use 'IResultFilter' which will implement

- OnResultExecuting
- OnResultExecuted

[The Base ActionFilterAttribute Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs)